# how can I clear up "training example lacks a goal" in Bixby #devjam2019 BLOCKS SUBMISSION

Tags: bixby

How can I clear up an error message saying "training example lacks a goal" when there is nothing to edit and no file in the training directory. (I suspect git mixup caused this corruption).

[image]

IMPORTANT because I can't submit this capsule with this error, it is a blocker.

Answer (score 2):

Quitting and restarting IDE cleared this up!